# Notify when we scroll to last position in RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, position

my app has a recycler view which scroll horizontally.
I want to trigger another event when i scroll the list and reached at last position.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Just implement a addOnScrollListener() on your recyclerview. Then inside the scroll listener implement the code below.

```
RecyclerView.OnScrollListener mScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        if (mIsLoading)
            return;
        int visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int pastVisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if (pastVisibleItems + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
            //End of list
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener nRecyclerViewOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int visibleItemCount = notificationLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = notificationLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = notificationLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount) {
            nLoadMoreItems();

        }
    }
};

private void nLoadMoreItems() {
    if (defaultCurrentPage < defaultpageCount)
        layout_load_more_loadingNotification.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    int pageCount = (defaultCurrentPage + 1);
   //fetch second page data
      }
```

try it

Comment: Thanks,
You can check my updated answer below @Safal

Answer (score 0):

after seeing all answer, I solve my problem by doing this,

```
 private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener nRecyclerViewOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (newState == 2) {
            try {
                if (lastVisibleItemPosition + 1 == totalItemCount) {
                    //Write you code here
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

    }
};
```

Add listener to recycler view

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(nRecyclerViewOnScrollListener);
```